# Import external metadata from web service to list

Tags: 2010

I've been given a task to import metadata from an external web service (which is itself interrogating a Trim CMS) into SharePoint 2010 list. I've been able to acheive the task by building a client application that uses the SharePoint 2010 client object model but now that I'm looking at options for deploying the application I'm wondering if there is a better option.

I've started reading about timer jobs, business connectivity services, content deployment paths and there are probably more options. Should I be doing my import using one of those approaches or something else rather than via an external application?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly I would be using the managed meta data service to store all your enterprise metadata.

Secondly you will need to write custom code that runs in the context of a timer job that will maintain the Term Sets in your managed metadata service to be in line with the external web service.

As long as your web applications are consuming the metadata service then all of them will have access to the latest metadata coming from your Trim CMS.

HTH.